# Combining binary classification algorithms

Tags: r, algorithm, machine-learning, classification, ensemble-learning

I have several algorithms which solve a binary classification (with response 0 or 1) problem by assigning to each observation a probability of the target value being equal to 1. All the algorithms try to minimize the [log loss function](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7BN%7D%5Csum_%7Bi=1%7D%5EN&space;%7B(y_i%5Clog(p_i)&space;+&space;(1&space;-&space;y_i)%5Clog(1&space;-&space;p_i))%7D) where N is the number of observations, y_i is the actual target value and p_i is the probability of 1 predicted by the algorithm. Here is some R code with sample data:

```
actual.response = c(1,0,0,0,1)
prediction.df = data.frame(
  method1 = c(0.5080349,0.5155535,0.5338271,0.4434838,0.5002529),
  method2 = c(0.5229466,0.5298336,0.5360780,0.4217748,0.4998602),
  method3 = c(0.5175378,0.5157711,0.5133765,0.4372109,0.5215695),
  method4 = c(0.5155535,0.5094510,0.5201827,0.4351625,0.5069823)
)

log.loss = colSums(-1/length(actual.response)*(actual.response*log(prediction.df)+(1-actual.response)*log(1-prediction.df)))
```

The sample code gives the log loss for each algorithm:

```
method1   method3   method2   method4 
0.6887705 0.6659796 0.6824404 0.6719181
```

Now I want to combine this algorithms so I can minimize the log loss even further. Is there any R package which can do this for me? I will appreciate references to any algorithms, articles, books or research papers which solve this kind of problem. Note that as a final result I want to have the predicted probabilities of each class and note plain 0,1 responses.

Answer (score 3):

This is called [ensemble learning (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning).

Check out this article: ["an intro to ensemble learning in r."](http://www.r-bloggers.com/an-intro-to-ensemble-learning-in-r/)

Here is an example I did using the [Cornell movie review data](http://Cornell%20movie%20review%20dataset) which can be downloaded by clicking the link. I used to data set with 1000 positive and 1000 negative reviews. Once you get the data into R:

```
library(RTextTools)
library(tm) 
library(glmnet)
library(ipred)
library(randomForest) 
library(data.table)

## create a column of sentiment score. 0 for negative and 1 for        
## positive. 

text_neg$pos_neg<-rep(0,1000)
text_pos$pos_neg<-rep(1,1000)

## Combine into 1 data.table and rename.

text_all<-rbind(text_neg, text_pos)
##dont forget to shuffle
set.seed(26)
text2<-text_all[sample(nrow(text_all)),]
## turn the data.frame into a document term matrix. This uses the handy 
##RTextTools wrappers and functions.

doc_matrix <- create_matrix(text2$V1, language="english", 
removeNumbers=TRUE, stemWords=TRUE, removeSparseTerms=.98)
ncol(data.frame(as.matrix(doc_matrix)))

## 2200 variables at .98 sparsity. runs pretty slow...
## create a container with the very nice RTextTools package

container <- create_container(doc_matrix, text2$pos_neg,  
trainSize=1:1700, testSize=1701:2000, virgin=FALSE)

## train the data
time_glm<-system.time(GLMNET <- train_model(container,"GLMNET"));    
time_glm #1.19
time_slda<-system.time(SLDA <- train_model(container,"SLDA"));   
time_slda #45.03
time_bag<-system.time(BAGGING <- train_model(container,"BAGGING"));   
time_bag #59.24
time_rf<-system.time(RF <- train_model(container,"RF")); time_rf #69.59

## classify with the models
GLMNET_CLASSIFY <- classify_model(container, GLMNET)
SLDA_CLASSIFY <- classify_model(container, SLDA)
BAGGING_CLASSIFY <- classify_model(container, BAGGING)
RF_CLASSIFY <- classify_model(container, RF)

## summarize results
analytics <- create_analytics(container,cbind( SLDA_CLASSIFY,  
BAGGING_CLASSIFY,RF_CLASSIFY, GLMNET_CLASSIFY))

summary(analytics)
```

This ran an ensemble classifier using the 4 different methods (random forests, GLM, SLD and bagging). The ensemble summary at the end shows

```
# ENSEMBLE SUMMARY
#
# n-ENSEMBLE COVERAGE   n-ENSEMBLE        RECALL
# n >= 1                1.00              0.86
# n >= 2                1.00              0.86
# n >= 3                0.89              0.89
# n >= 4                0.63              0.96
```

That if all 4 methods agreed on if the review was positive or negative, then the ensemble had a 96% recall rate. But be careful, because with a binary outcome (2 choices) and 4 different algorithms, there is bound to be a lot of agreement.

See the `RTextTools` documentation for more explanation. They also do an almost identical example with U.S Congress data that I more or less mimicked in the above example.

Hope this was helpful.